# How to stop datawatch on zookeeper node using kazoo?

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper, kazoo

How to explicitly stop datawatch process started on a zNode using python module kazoo?
Below is the way I created datawatch

```
from   kazoo.recipe.watchers    import DataWatch
datawatch = DataWatch(client=zookeeper_client, path=path_to_znode, func=callback_function)
```

I went through [kazoo wiki](http://kazoo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and figured out below ways.

1. Returning False from callback method passed(here callback_function) will stop datawatch on the zNode.
   But this way is not suitable for me as callback_function is handled by users and not in my hand.
2. When process stops datawatch automatically gets killed. But I don't want to stop the process.
3. This is the hacky way I am using currently.
   There is a private member variable "_stopped" under datawatch class. I am setting it to true.

   ```
   datawatch._stopped = True
   ```

Can someone please suggest better solution here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [DataWatch Doc](https://kazoo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/recipe/watchers.html#kazoo.recipe.watchers.DataWatch) also says:

> If the client connection is closed (using the close command), the DataWatch will no longer get updates.
>   So stopping the zookeeper client should be enough.

```
from kazoo.client import KazooClient

zk = KazooClient(hosts='127.0.0.1:2181')
zk.start()
datawatch = DataWatch(client=zk, path=path_to_znode, func=callback_function)
# time pass....
zk.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks @Lorenzo, But I already mentioned in point 2 of my question that my case do not allow me to close the client connection.